# Passing javascript variable to PHP function

Tags: php, javascript

I have this javascript code

```
<Script>
    function getGroupId(){
        var group=document.getElementById("selectedOptions").value;
        var groupFirstLetter=group.substring(2);

    }
</Script>
```

I need to pass the `groupFirstLetter` to a PHP function which will count how many users in this group and return the value to the javascript function.

Any ideas please?

Thanks,

Comment: there are only 2 ways to archieve that. 1. Ajax 2. reload page. JS runs in your client, PHP on the server. as soon as you requested a page and got your answer there is nothing happening on the server anymore (except for sockets or ajax). Without those 2 options you cant let js communicate with php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery for that to post an AJAX request. See this example taken out of jQuery documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: {groupFirstLetter:groupFirstLetter},
  complete: function(data){
            //data contains the response from the php file.
            //u can pass it here to the javascript function
        }
});
```

The variable will be available in your PHP code as `$_POST['groupFirstLetter']`.
You can manipulate it as you wish then `echo` a response to the browser again and it will be available in the `data` variable.
references:

[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

As javascript runs on user's browser you have to do an http request to a php page. POST or GET can be used to send parameters.

To make a http call with javascript refer to this: [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery (jquery.com).

Dynamically load the php-file sending the variable using ajax like so:

```
$.post("file.php", {variable_name: value}, function(returned_data){
    console.log(returned_data); //or do whatever you like with the variable
});
```

and your php-file will access the variable as:

```
$_POST['variable_name'];
```